# Foreign controller : Unrecognised selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've seen similar questions asked a thousand times and I usually can answer these… However this time I am the one stumped with the same error.

I have a UIViewController implementing the following code :

.H

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MMRHomeViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

.M

```
#import "MMRHomeViewController.h"
#import "MMRPageTwoViewController.h"
#import "MMRMenuViewController.h"

@interface MMRHomeViewController ()

@end

@implementation MMRHomeViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.navigationItem.title = @"HOME";
    UIImage *menuImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu.png"];
    UIBarButtonItem *menuBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:menuImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:(MMRMenuViewController *)self action:@selector(showMenu)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuBtn;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Go to next page Action
- (IBAction)goToPage2:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *pageTwoCtrl = [[MMRPageTwoViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:pageTwoCtrl animated:YES];
}

@end
```

Rather straightforward. I am trying to call the showMenu() method on the MMRMenuViewController view Controller.

Here is the code in the MMRMenuViewController.m :

```
- (void)showMenu
{
    NSLog(@"Show menu");
}
```

Yet again, dead simple.

I have checked that the #import "MMRMenuViewController.h" is present, that my MMRMenuViewController.h implements "- (void)showMenu;"

Here is the MMRMenuViewController code :

.H
    #import

```
@interface MMRMenuViewController : UIViewController

- (void)showMenu;

@end
```

.M

```
#import "MMRMenuViewController.h"

@interface MMRMenuViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *avatarImageView;

@end

@implementation MMRMenuViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.avatarImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 38.0;

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"view did Load");
    NSLog(@"Self = %@", self);
    NSLog(@"Self avatarImageView = %@", self.avatarImageView);
    NSLog(@"Self View = %@", self.view);

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.avatarImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 38.0;
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    CGRect menuViewFrame = self.view.frame;
    menuViewFrame.origin.x = - [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
    self.view.frame = menuViewFrame;
}

- (void)showMenu
 {
     NSLog(@"Show menu");
     //[self.navigationController.view insertSubview:self.view aboveSubview:self.view.superview];
}

@end
```

The problem is I keep getting the following error :

2014-06-06 13:28:24.705 BHSideBar[23137:60b] -[MMRHomeViewController showMenu]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109416f00
2014-06-06 13:28:28.516 BHSideBar[23137:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MMRHomeViewController showMenu]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109416f00'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010194a495 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001016a999e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001019db65d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010193bd8d ___forwarding_** + 973
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010193b938 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000100257f06 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 80
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000100257f06 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 80
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000100257eb4 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 17
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000100334880 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 203
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000100333dc0 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 530
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010028ed05 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 701
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010028f6e4 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 925
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010026729a -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 211
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000100254aed _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 9579
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001018d9d21 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001018d95f2 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001018f546f __CFRunLoopRun + 767
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001018f4d83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000103ac1f04 GSEventRunModal + 161
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000100256e33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
    20  BHSideBar                           0x00000001000022e3 main + 115
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000101fe25fd start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

And I can't for the life of me figure out where I am going wrong. It's probably dead simple but I haven't been able to solve it and it is driving me crazy. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

"showMenu" and "showMenu:" are not the same method.

One is a method with no parameters, the other is a method with one parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `showMenu:` (which has a parameter) instead of `showMenu`.

Edit : You're calling `showMenu` on a `MMRHomeViewController` object which hasn't a method declared `showMenu`. Call it on a `MMRMenuViewController` and it will surely work.

Comment: You are right !!! How did I miss that. OK. Now I get a totally different error, but I guess it's because I am not allowed to do this.
MMRMenuViewController *menuViewCtrl = [[MMRMenuViewController alloc] init];
    UIBarButtonItem *menuBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:menuImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:(MMRMenuViewController *)menuViewCtrl action:@selector(showMenu)];

Isn't it possible to pass a message to another controller ?

Comment: First, move your button creation to homeviewcontroller's `viewDidLoad`, I guess it's a button from there, you want to press it there and show the menu. Second, `... target:self action:@selector(showMenu)` because you want to call your homeviewcontroller's showMenu method, right ? In that method you instantiate the menu viewcontroller and add it to view hierarchy in some way.

Comment: Actually what I was trying to do was add a sidebar menu class. A reusable class. Solved the issue by accessing via the navigationController.

Answer (score 1):

Now it looks like that `-showMenu` is being called on wrong object. Check the object type and if that object implements `-showMenu`.

Comment: I am not calling showMenu: but showMenu… no parametres…
You misread the error

Comment: That is why it I said how `showMenu` should be, not how it is. `showMenu` and `showMenu:` both are different.

Comment: Thanks.My answer wasn't clear enough. I meant that I am calling showMenu nor parametres AND getting the error -[MMRHomeViewController showMenu]: unrecognized selector sent to instance NO parametre. You misread the error :-)

Comment: Another possibility is that showMenu is being called on the wrong type of the object (on some other object). Please check the type of object.

Comment: Yes… I had also thought of that. But if I log the object just before the call method, I do get the correct object ie MMRMenuViewController

Answer (score 1):

Not enough information. Show the complete error message from the console. Map out the sending view controller, the destination view controller, how the are created, and how they get pointers to each other. You should probably provide the headers for both view controllers.

Post the code that's calling showMenu.

Then when you get ready to call showMenu in your MMRMenuViewController, set a breakpoint and log the class of the object you are trying to send the showMenu message.

The 2 most likely causes are that your target object is not a MMRMenuViewController when you think it is, or that the method signature is different, e.g. you're trying to send a parameter, or the capitalization is different.

Comment: I have posted the code where I call the method :
UIBarButtonItem *menuBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:menuImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:(MMRMenuViewController *)self action:@selector(showMenu)];

Comment: I've added all the code… Also tried tour suggestions… but to no avail. The pointers seem correct.

Answer (score -1):

Well… after a while searching it appears I cannot access another controller via the target attribute. So, what I had to do was pass the action to the navigationController since that is accessible by the current Controller.

Thanks all for your patience and helpful answers.